# File full path location using php

Tags: php, file

i am creating file upload script and saving the file path to the sql, i use this script

```
$location = 'files/' . $file_name;
$full_path = realpath($location);
```

It return

```
D:xampphtdocsau
```

why theres no slash, am i doing it wrong

Comment: This "realpath()" function removes all symbolic links (like '/./', '/../' and extra '/') and returns the absolute pathname.

Comment: You are running on a windows OS?

Comment: yes i am running windows

Comment: Please show us `var_dump(realpath($location));`